# Dynamic attributes in hibernate mapping from front-end

Tags: json, angular, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I am trying to insert JSON data to our database using Spring Boot, Hibernate and Angular. The attribute name in this JSON data is unknown at compile time.

Is there any possibility we can use an ORM to insert this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonAnySetter. This decorator lets you to define a method in your model class which will receive unrecognized fields. Serialize them and write them in another field. Later, use @JsonAnyGetter for reading your data.

Pseudo-code:

```
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "table")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "key")
  @Column(name = "value")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Map<String, String> any;
  .
  .
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setAny(String name, String value) {
    any.put(name, value);
  }
  .
  .
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public Map<String, Object> getAny() {
    return any;
  }
```

Comment: I was asking that the column name of the table will be the key in the JSON object and each value of the key is the corresponding value of the table...The table will be already in the database.I have to insert the data using JPA and hibernate.So is there any possibility to use dynamic attributes in POJO class?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In the database, the table associated to your entity will be untouched but an auxiliar table will be needed for storing dynamic attributes (look ```Map<String, String> any``` with ```@CollectionTable``` annotation).